# Docker pip install creates recursive tmp/pip-build/tmp/pip-build... folder

Tags: python, docker, recursion, pip, setup.py

I'm a bit new to Docker and Python apps. I was running into a really perplexing problem, and after a bit of button-pushing, I miraculously solved it. However, I understand neither the problem nor the solution, and want to understand both.

So I have a Dockerfile in the root directory of my app that does something like this:

```
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y enchant \
  && pip install --extra-index-url=${ARTIFACTORY} --no-cache-dir requirements.txt \
  && pip install . \ # installs my python app using setup.py
  && python -m app.run_model
ENTRYPOINT ...
```

This was failed consistently because it ran out of disk space. Ok, fine, I deleted old, unused images. But I don't think that was the issue, because it kept failing, and was also generating these super long, super weird recursive filenames like:

```
/tmp/pip-fih7z5-build/tmp/pip-fih7z5-build/tmp/pip-fih7z5-build/tmp/pip-fih7z5-build/tmp/pip-fih7z5-build/tmp/pip-fih7z5-build/tmp/pip-fih7z5-build/tmp/pip-fih7z5-build/tmp/pip-fih7z5-build/tmp/pip-fih7z5-build/tmp/pip-fih7z5-build/...
```

Adding the following wrapper around the Docker command somehow worked:

```
COPY . /workdir
RUN cd /workdir \
...
  && rm -rf /workdir
```

To get past the installation phase (although now it appears like the app process is still failing.) I'm not sure what was/is going on. Does anyone have any insight? My best guess is somehow the two `pip install`s were creating some sort of recursive nightmare?

My `setup.py` is pretty standard, I think:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from glob import glob
from os.path import abspath, basename, dirname, join, splitext
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

here = abspath(dirname(__file__))

with open(join(here, 'README.md')) as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    py_modules=[splitext(basename(path))[0] for path in glob('src/*.py')],
    zip_safe=False,
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
    'scikit-learn==0.18.1',
    'scipy==0.19.1',
    'nltk==3.2.3',
    'requests==2.17.3',
    'jsonschema==2.6.0',
    'pandas==0.20.1',
    'numpy==1.13.0',
    'textblob==0.12.0',
    'textstat==0.3.1',
    'langdetect==1.0.7',
    'unidecode==0.4.20',
    'Flask==0.12.1',
    'Flask-Env==1.0.1',
    'pyenchant==1.6.11'
    ],
    setup_requires=[
        'flake8==3.3.0',
    ],
    tests_require=[],
)
```

```

Comment: I do think you want to be as explicit as possible with the second pip install, the one for your app.  I try to be just so there is no guessing on what I try to do when I come back to a project after having been away from it for some time.

Comment: Are you executing "RUN apt update" early in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Post your setup.py. Also change `pip install .` to `python setup.py install` and see if it helps

Comment: @jomunculus, I think I am? Is `&& apt-get update && apt-get install -y ...` what you mean?

Comment: thanks @TarunLalwani, I posted the ```setup.py```

Comment: @AlexSpangher yes.  You have the RUN command split over a few lines, but yes.